# Laravel 5: Controller subdirectory and Route Group with multiple Controller does not work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Its might be a bug in laravel but not sure, need your suggestions about to resolve this.

The issue is when you use more than one controller under route:group with controller subdirectory except one controller other would be 404s.
Here's my detail code review for senerio:

**Routes**

```
#routes.php
#Settings
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'setting'), function() {
    #Index
    Route::controller('/', 'Setting\IndexController',[
        'getIndex'=>'index/setting'
    ]);
    #company detail
    Route::controller('company', 'Setting\CompanyController',[
        'getInfo'=>'info/company',
        'getEdit'=>'update/company'
    ]);
});
```

**Controllers**

IndexController.php

```
#/app/Http/Controllers/Setting/IndexController.php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Setting;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class IndexController extends Controller {
    public function getIndex(){
        return "setting.index";
    }

}
```

CompanyController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Setting;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class CompanyController extends Controller {

    public function getInfo(){
        return ('setting.company.index');
    }

    public function getEdit(){
        return ('setting.company.edit');
    }
}
```

Currently its not working but when you comment one route::controller other will work fine and viceversa.
and also if remove one route:controller and add route like:

```
Route::get('/', array('as' => 'index/setting', 'uses' => 'Setting\IndexController@getIndex'));
```

than both will work fine.

But I need to use route:controller for all controllers under route:group.

So, if still there something missing to explain let me know, I will update further in depth.
Any help would be appreciable.